# create time series data in 24 hours format in r

Tags: r, time-series

```
time_index <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2012-08-25 00:00"),
              to  = as.POSIXct("2014-09-25 23:00"),
              by = "hour")
ts_data <- xts(x = train$Count,
           order.by = time_index)
```

Using the above code I've created a time series data. This is a traffic data detailing how many vehicles visited a particular signal.

I would like to find the traffic patterns in the data. The data contains the hourly count of vehicles each hour.

Now the question is how to convert this data to have 24 columns with dates in the rows of the time series and hours in the columns?

I'm using R programming to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following codes might be an useful example to solve your problem.

```
require(tidyverse)
ts_data<-as.data.frame(ts_data)
ts_data$datetime<-rownames(ts_data)
ts_data<-ts_data %>% separate(datetime,into=c("date","time"),sep=" ") 
ts_data<-ts_data %>% separate(time,into=c("HH","MM","SS")) 
ts_data<-ts_data %>% select(V1,date,HH)
colnames(ts_data)<-c("count","date","HH")
ts_data<-ts_data %>% spread(date,count)
```

Since I'm not familiar with xts object, I converted it into data.frame.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you @BJK. Solved the problem.